# change fillColor of selected CAShapeLayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation, calayer

I'm trying to change the fillColor of a CAShapeLayer when the
layer it's contained in is touched.
I'm able to change the background color of the tapped layer like this:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
CALayer *layer = [(CALayer *)self.view.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:point];
layer = layer.modelLayer;
layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
}
```

This turns the background of "layer" blue as expected.
My problem is how do I change the color of the CAShapelayer inside "layer"?
Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A `CAShapeLayer` has a property, `fillColor`, that you can pass in a `CGColor` to change:

```
CAShapeLayer* shapeLayer = (CAShapeLayer*)layer.modelLayer;
shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
```

See also: [CAShapeLayer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: That's true. But the `.fillColor` property should be run on the **Main Thread**. If this statement is not run, please consider this statement is running on the main thread or not.